# Initializing member in Getter or Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor, getter

Is there is a difference between these two approaches ?

In this approach I am using the getter to initialize the DataTable

```
public DataTable Res
{
    get
    {
        if (Res == null)
        {
            Res = GetDataTable();
        }
        return Res ;
    }
    private set;
}
```

vs.

In this approach I am using the constructor to initialize the DataTable

```
public class XYZ
{
    public DataTable Res{ get; private set;}
    //constructor 
    public XYZ()
    {
        Res= GetDataTable();            
    }
}
```

This variable is used on an ASP.net page to fill a DropDown List. Which will perform better ?

Edit:-

This is used in a web application where data will not change. I bind this table to a dropdown list in Page_Load event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is whether a given instance of class `XYZ` will always need and use the `DataTable`.

If not, then you'd want to lazy-initialize (using your getter), so as to avoid doing the work up front for nothing.

If you will always need it, then the next question is whether there is potentially any substantive delay between instantiation of the class and a call to the `Res` property. If so, then loading the data upon instantiation could mean your data is a bit more stale than it would be if you waited until the property getter is called.

The flip-side to that is not necessarily applicable in a web scenario, but in other applications one would want to consider whether a call to the property needs to be highly responsive to keep the UI from freezing. Preloading the data might be preferable in such a scenario.

Comment: This is used in a web application where data will not change. I bind this table to a dropdown list in Page_Load event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a difference.  The first method is called lazy instantiation, which means you wait until the object is used before it is instantiated.  The nice thing about doing this is that you are waiting until the last possible second to use up the memory and processor that is required to setup the object.

The second method instantiates the object as soon as you create the class.  The downside of doing this is if you never use the object, then you wasted the time to create the object and the memory while the object was allocated.

Comment: Thanks! that was fast i was not even finished typing my Question :)

Comment: Just a note that in the event that you use the DataTable every time the performance differences are either none or negligible.

Comment: Thanks. that was my follow up question as i know i will always use this datatable as i am filling my dropdown list on page load